# Updating a div on collection update in meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor

This is my first meteor app. It's primarily inspired from [this blog post](http://info.meteor.com/blog/whatsapp-with-meteor-angular-and-ionic). I use  `ng-switch` to display different messages like:

```
<ng-switch on="message.type">
  <!-- Text Widget -->
  <div ng-switch-when="text" class="text">
    {{ message.text }}
  </div>
  <!-- Picture Widget -->
  <div ng-switch-when="picture" class="picture">
    <img ng-click="trackClick($event, message)" ng-src="{{message.picture}}">
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Widget -->
  <div ng-switch-when="dynamic" class="dynamic">
    <div class="content" ng-click="trackClick($event, message)">{{ message.content }}</div>
  </div>
```

The way this app behaves is as follows:

- User enters a text, a meteor collection is updated and the corresponding text widget shows up
- A DDP client (in Ruby) listens for any `add` event in the collection. It updates the collection with a `text` or `image` or `dynamic` content.
- The frontend creates a new DOM element and displays the content in that element.

However, I have a special content type called `dynamic` where I do not want to create a new DOM element (everytime), but rather edit the content of existing DOM element.

The way I think to achieve this is to edit the corresponding Mongo entry without adding a new one. But is there a way I could have this functionality when I have to add a new entry?

Comment: read "reactive-var" meteor

Comment: Thanks, it did answer some of my questions. However, how do I bind a template state to a data object that gets updated dynamically (from backend?)

Comment: Also, it seems to be tightly coupled to *one* template. Is it possible to use a reactive-dict to be bound with multiple templates? It looks like reactjs is better suited for such architectures compared to meteor

Comment: just sample example from my code. It may help you.
var svgController = [];
Template.hello.onCreated(function() {
    svgController = new ReactiveVar();
    svgController.set([])
});

  Template.hello.helpers({
    controllers: function () {
        return svgController.get();
    }
  });

Comment: just set "svgController.set("<mydata>")" whenever you want to refresh your DOM